# ParseQueryAdapter is loading images incorrectly

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a ParseQueryAdapter set up but it appears that the images are not being properly loaded. I have a total of 10 objects, the newest 3 with images.

My adapter is pulling all these objects into a ListView fine with the adapter, but it appears that not only are the 3 objects with pictures displaying, but some of the other objects are displaying these same pictures, even though they're not supposed to since theres no images for the objects.

What can be the cause for this? Notice when I scroll the bottom few, will alternate with taking the pics from the top three items in the list.

Adapter

```
public class LocalSalesAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Sale> {

    public LocalSalesAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Sale>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public ParseQuery<Sale> create() {

                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Sales");
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Sale sale, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.listview_local_sales_cell, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(sale, v, parent);

        ParseImageView saleImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ParseFile photoFile = sale.getParseFile("photo");
        if (photoFile != null) {
            saleImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            saleImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                }
            });
        }

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listView_localSalesSubject);
        titleTextView.setText(sale.getSaleTitle());
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listView_localSalesDescription);
        descriptionTextView.setText(sale.getSaleDescription());
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_listView_localSalesPrice);
        priceTextView.setText(sale.getSalePrice());
        return v;
    }

}
```

Activity

```
public class LocalSalesActivity extends ListActivity {
    ListView mLocalSales;

    ParseUser mCurrentUser;
    String mTAG = "LocalSalesActivity";

    private LocalSalesAdapter localSalesAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_sales);
        mLocalSales = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        localSalesAdapter = new LocalSalesAdapter(this);

        setListAdapter(localSalesAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    }
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public void presentUserWithLogin() {
        // Displaying the Login Activity to the user
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        // Logging in =  New Task, Old Task = Clear so back button cannot be used to go back into Profile Activity if logged out.
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.local_sales, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.action_log_out:
            // Logging out the current user and presenting them with the login activity.
            ParseUser.logOut();
            presentUserWithLogin();
            break;
        case R.id.action_post_sale:
            // Launching new intent to start Post Sale Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PostSaleActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break; 
        case R.id.action_profile_activity:
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear your ParseImageView somehow in case if `photoFile == null`. For example set transparent color as an image resource. So modify your `getItemView(...)` method of the `LocalSalesAdapter` class in the following way:

```
@Override
public View getItemView(Sale sale, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    ParseImageView saleImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile photoFile = sale.getParseFile("photo");
    if (photoFile != null) {
        saleImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
        saleImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            }
        });
    } else { // Clear ParseImageView if an object doesn't have a photo
        saleImage.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }

    ...
}
```